# How to create an IN query on Parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I need to create a query with multiples values for a property, I think something like:

```
var MyObject = Parse.Object.extend('MyObject');
var query = new Parse.Query(MyObject);
query.limit(10);
query.in('property', ['value1', 'value2', ..., 'valueN']);
query.count().then(function(count) {
    console.log(count);
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: try the equalTo multiple times  e.g. query.equalTo('value1');query.equalTo('value2');...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with **containedIn**

```
var options = ['value1', 'value2', ..., 'valueN'];
query.containedIn('property', options);
query.count().then(function(count) {
...
..
.});
```

see https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Query.html#containedIn

Have fun!